# Simple if statement with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Somehow the if statement does not work, although the else part does work. In the given example console logs "menu toggled" and "menu toggled, else works", but "menu toggled, if works" is not triggered.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

```js
var body = document.body;
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuButton');
var menuActive = "menu-active";
var color = "color";
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

$(menuToggle).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(menu).toggleClass(menuActive);
  console.log('menu toggled');
  
  if ($(menu).is(menuActive)) {
    console.log('menu toggled, if works');
    $(body).addClass(color);
  } else {
    console.log('menu toggled, else works');
    $(body).removeClass(color);
  }
});
```

```css
.color {
  background: orange;
}

.menu-active {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="menuButton">menu</button>

<nav class="menu" id="menu" aria-label="Main menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using jQuery because with vanilla JavaScript cant get menu working on older devices (i.e. iOS 9). For jQueries `.is` used vanilla JavaScript `.classList.contains`, which did work...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.is` function takes a *selector*, not a class name, eg:

```
 $(menu).is("." + menuActive)
```

you could also use `.hasClass` to check specifically for a class name, eg:

```
 $(menu).hasClass(menuActive)
```

Updated snippet that @isherwood helpfully added:

```js
var body = document.body;
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuButton');
var menuActive = "menu-active";
var color = "color";
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

$(menuToggle).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(menu).toggleClass(menuActive);
  console.log('menu toggled');
  
  if ($(menu).is("." + menuActive)) {
    console.log('menu toggled, if works');
    $(body).addClass(color);
  } else {
    console.log('menu toggled, else works');
    $(body).removeClass(color);
  }
});
```

```css
.color {
  background: orange;
}

.menu-active {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="menuButton">menu</button>

<nav class="menu" id="menu" aria-label="Main menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why even with jQuery menu does not toggles on older devices, i.e. iOS 9?

Answer (score 2):

To check for a class existance use `hasClass` rather that using `is`.

jQuery `is` method is used to check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```js
var body = document.body;
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuButton');
var menuActive = "menu-active";
var color = "color";
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');


$(menuToggle).on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(menu).toggleClass(menuActive);
  console.log('menu toggled');
  // if ($(menu).is(menuActive)) {
  if($(menu).hasClass(menuActive)) {
    console.log('menu toggled, if works');
    $(body).addClass(color);
  } else {
    console.log('menu toggled, else works');
    $(body).removeClass(color);
  }
});
```

```css
.color {
  background: orange;
}

.menu-active {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menuButton">menu</button>
<nav class="menu" id="menu" aria-label="Main menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Working example for `jQuery` `is` method.

```js
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuButton');
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

$(menuToggle).on('click', function (e) {
  console.log($(menu).is('nav'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menuButton">menu</button>
<nav class="menu" id="menu" aria-label="Main menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why even with jQuery menu does not toggles on older devices, i.e. iOS 9?